# how to use QSortFilterProxyModel for filter a 2d array?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have been struggling with this for a while, and i am not even sure i am using the right pyqt classes.

I have a QTableView that display a 2d array of integers and i wish to filter it to only show the integer under a value.

This is the example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import random

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = 3
        self._parent = parent

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return int( float( len( self._parent.data ) ) / float( self._columns ) )+1

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return self._columns

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid(): 
            return None

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: 
            try:
                value = self._parent.data[ index.row() * self._columns + index.column() ]
            except:
                pass
            else:
                return value

        return None


class tableProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(tableProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._parent = parent
        self.filterColumn = []
        self.filterRow = []
        self.maxFilter =0

    def setFilter(self, value):
        #
        #  this will find the 2d position of the datas that need to be kept visible
        #  we need a list of the row and column axis 
        #
        self.maxFilter = value
        self.filterColumn = []
        self.filterRow = []

        for i in self._parent.data:
            if i < self.maxFilter:
                positionInList = [j for j,x in enumerate( self._parent.data ) if x == i][0]
                filterRow, filterColumn = self.getPosition( positionInList )
                self.filterColumn.append(filterColumn)
                self.filterRow.append(filterRow)

        self.invalidateFilter()

    def getPosition(self, value):
        #
        #  convert data list to a 2d array 
        #
        leftOver = value%self._parent._tm._columns
        filterRow = (value-leftOver) / self._parent._tm._columns
        filterColumn = leftOver
        return filterRow, filterColumn

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):

        model = self.sourceModel()

        if  row in self.filterRow:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def filterAcceptsColumn(self, column, parent):
        model = self.sourceModel()

        if column  in self.filterColumn:
            return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__=="__main__":
    from sys import argv, exit

    class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

            self.data = [ d for d in range(10) ]
            ###################################################
            ## this line shuffle the list, if you quote this line and keep the list in order , then the example works as expected
            random.shuffle(self.data)
            print self.data

            l=QtGui.QVBoxLayout( self )
            self._tm=TableModel( self )
            self._tv=QtGui.QTableView( )

            self._tpm=tableProxyModel( self )
            self._tpm.setSourceModel( self._tm )
            self._tv.setModel( self._tpm )
            l.addWidget( self._tv )

            #################################################
            ## apply the filter, only show numbers under 5
            self._tpm.setFilter(5)

    a=QtGui.QApplication(argv)
    w=Widget()
    w.show()
    w.raise_()
    exit(a.exec_())
```

If you execute this example, you can see it doesn't only show the values under 5 ...

How can i filter a QTableView filled with random values ? I wish to use the model/view system here.

Comment: with a table model you can only filter rows or columns, element by element is not filtered, so my question is: if an element of a row is greater than 5 that row should be accepted or not? Would a row be valid only if all the numbers are less than 5? Will the filtering be per row or per column?

Comment: well i guess you answered my question "with a table model you can only filter rows or columns, element by element is not filtered". My aim is to filter element per element and validate which one should be in the table. In this example, only display elements under 5... if i use another pyqt proxyModel class, would i be able to achieve this ?

Comment: no, you can not do it with QSortFilterProxyModel since, as I said, it filters only by row or by column, also keep in mind that this filtering is visual, for example if the table were`[[10, 5, 3], [10, 3, 12 ], [12, 5, 5]]` how should it be shown?

Comment: If you had a model type list that is displayed in a QListView you could do that type of filtering because a row would have an element, so hiding a row would hide an element.

Comment: yes i understand what you mean. i can't use QSortFilterProxyModel  to achieve what iam looking for.

Comment: but QListView would display as a list ? i wish to display an array.

Comment: Exactly, on the other hand maybe I can give you an alternative but what I do not understand is that since you want an element to be hidden, if in a row there is an element that does not comply with the rule that would mean hiding that element?

Comment: to understand it better, you could show an image of the output you want using the data as input: `[[10, 5, 3], [10, 3, 12 ], [12, 5, 5]]` and `maxFilter=5`

Comment: if in a row there is an element that does not comply with the rule that would mean hiding that element? > yes

Comment: But what does it mean to hide? Does it mean not showing the number? Does it mean to paint it another color? what does it mean?

Comment: [[10, 5, 3], [10, 3, 12 ], [12, 5, 5]] so this would be filtered as [ [5,3,3], [5,5]]

Comment: but that is no longer a table

Comment: Since i use the model/view system, the proxyModel takes care of filtering and the model only display what the proxyModel left. To me that is the most elegant way.

Comment: a table has nxm elements in your case would be 3x2 what value should be shown in the sixth box?.

Comment: the sixth box could be empty, a none or empty string would be fine.

Comment: that form is not elegant, it is stinky, if you are going to do it better do not use QSortFilterProxyModel, for example if you are going to have 1 Million of data, do you think that filtering it in a loop will be efficient ?, then no, the idea of filterAcceptsXXX is that use when you need, and in your case you are doing it at the beginning, and if you add more data to the model, do you have to run the same loop for the data already filtered? Do you think that is efficient?

Comment: I already have an idea, my idea is to convert that table to a list by means of a proxy, and in the list it will be filtered, after that I will convert that list into a table through another proxy, although it seems a lot of code will be more efficient than your solution.

Comment: i see what you mean, in my case i was trying to stay withing the model/view system laid out in pyqt as much as possible. But i think i am at the limit here ? what would you advice ?

Comment: It is that you are not using MVC, you are in charge of filtering instead of Qt doing it when necessary, I am already working on a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSortFilterProxyModel` only filters columns or rows, it does not filter elements, so the strategy for this case is to convert the table into a list, then filter the list since filtering a row is equivalent to filtering an element and finally converting the list into a table.

```
import random
import math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, columns, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = columns
        self._data = data[:]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        if parent.isValid() or self._columns == 0:
            return 0
        return math.ceil(len(self._data )*1.0/self._columns)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._columns

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid(): 
            return
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: 
            try:
                value = self._data[ index.row() * self._columns + index.column() ]
                return value
            except:
                pass

class Table2ListProxyModel(QtGui.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self.sourceModel().rowCount() * self.sourceModel().columnCount()

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        if sourceIndex.isValid() and sourceIndex.column() == 0 \
                and sourceIndex.row() < self.rowCount():
            r = sourceIndex.row()
            c = sourceIndex.column()
            row = c * sourceIndex.model().columnCount() + r
            return self.index(row, 0)
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        r = proxyIndex.row() / self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        c = proxyIndex.row() % self.sourceModel().columnCount()
        return self.sourceModel().index(r, c)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)


class ListFilterProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def setThreshold(self, value):
        setattr(self, "threshold", value)
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if hasattr(self, "threshold"):
            ix = self.sourceModel().index(row, 0)
            val = ix.data()
            if val is None:
                return False
            return val < getattr(self, "threshold")
        return True


class List2TableProxyModel(QtGui.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, columns=1, parent=None):
        super(List2TableProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = columns

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self._columns

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return math.ceil(self.sourceModel().rowCount()/self._columns)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        r = index.row()
        c = index.column()
        row = r * self.columnCount() + c
        if row < self.sourceModel().rowCount():
            return super(List2TableProxyModel, self).data(index, role)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        r = math.ceil(sourceIndex.row() / self.columnCount())
        c = sourceIndex.row() % self.columnCount()
        return self.index(r, c)

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        if proxyIndex.isValid():
            r = proxyIndex.row()
            c = proxyIndex.column()
            row = r * self.columnCount() + c
            return self.sourceModel().index(row, 0)
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        data = [random.choice(range(10)) for i in range(20)]

        l = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        splitter = QtGui.QSplitter()
        l.addWidget(splitter)

        tv = QtGui.QTableView()
        lv = QtGui.QListView()
        lvf = QtGui.QListView()
        tvf = QtGui.QTableView()

        model = TableModel(data, 3, self)
        proxy1 = Table2ListProxyModel(self)
        proxy1.setSourceModel(model)
        proxy2 = ListFilterProxyModel(self)
        proxy2.setSourceModel(proxy1)
        proxy2.setThreshold(5)
        proxy3 = List2TableProxyModel(3, self)
        proxy3.setSourceModel(proxy2)

        tv.setModel(model)
        lv.setModel(proxy1)
        lvf.setModel(proxy2)
        tvf.setModel(proxy3)

        splitter.addWidget(tv)
        splitter.addWidget(lv)
        splitter.addWidget(lvf)
        splitter.addWidget(tvf)


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    a=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! i would never thought of a solution like this by myself! i didn't realized it  would be that difficult to achieve as well. I will probably adjust it to my need, but at least now i get what was the issue.

Comment: I am having some trouble with delegates with this example.  When i use the proxy model 3 on the qtableview the table ignore the delegate. If i dont use the proxy then it shows the qdelegate correctly.

Comment: @nicosalto Without a [mcve] I can not help you so I invite you to create a new question giving more details of the delegate, etc.

Comment: @nicosalto Do not edit the question, create a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) since the question is different.

Comment: Of course, there is a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550903/how-to-use-qitemdelegate-with-multiple-proxy-models-stacked