# how to add widgets in every a qtableView cell with a MVC design?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

Here is a simple example of a qtableView where every cell have a different item. In the example here i used numbers, but ultimately i wish to display animated gifs for every cells. I wish to keep the MVC design and insert a custom widget proceduraly.

```
import random
import math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, columns, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = columns
        self._data = data[:]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        if parent.isValid() or self._columns == 0:
            return 0
        return math.ceil(len(self._data )*1.0/self._columns)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._columns

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid(): 
            return
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: 
            try:
                value = self._data[ index.row() * self._columns + index.column() ]
                return value
            except:
                pass

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        data = [random.choice(range(10)) for i in range(20)]

        l = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        splitter = QtGui.QSplitter()
        l.addWidget(splitter)

        tvf = QtGui.QTableView()
        model = TableModel(data, 3, self)
        tvf.setModel(model)

        splitter.addWidget( tvf )


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    a=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

After reading a bit more and with the help of @eyllanesc, i understand that there is 2 ways of achieving this: delegates or itemWidget.
It seem that delegates won't work for me since it's not possible to insert widget into cells that way.
ItemWidget seems the way to go but this is not MVC compatible ? i do not wish to loop the function to insert into the table...

is there a third way ?

Comment: You cannot plug in any widget when using delegates but it's certainly possible to draw an image in each cell. See the [Pixelator Example from the Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-pixelator-example.html) (Python port [here](https://github.com/pyqt/examples/blob/master/itemviews/pixelator/pixelator.py)). Making them animated would require some more work though.

Comment: It occurs to me that, if you really want to show an animated gif in *every* cell (as opposed to *some*), a table may not be the best choice. Perhaps the [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) is a better choice. Can you edit your post and tell us what you're making?